# Flask script as a toggle service

Tags: python, flask

I have a function having a forever running loop:

```
def some_function():
    while True:
         #some tasks here
```

I need to write a Flask script such that when a request comes, the execution of this function should start if it is stopped and vice versa. So, for example, for a function like this:

```
def some_function():
    count = 0
    while True:
         print(count)
         sleep(5)
```

I need something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def toggle():
    if function_isnt_running():
        start_function_execution()
        return Response('Started')
    else:
        stop_function_execution()
        return Response('Stopped')
```

Comment: you need create your function as separate python script and call it as async subprocess, so your function keep running and flsk can give back an answer; Otherwise the function keep looping and your flask request  will enter in timeout

Comment: @Carlo1585 I tried something similar and it worked. But is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: seeing that u want it run all the time the alernative is to create a system service that run with parameters and as soon you call the API it stop the service and restart with different parameters. But you have to deal with system library, not difficult to do in a UNIX Server but I'm not sure what you are using

Comment: I'm using a Linux machine

Comment: both solution do what u need, the script is the same and u need use os library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html you just need decide if it should be just a script that is in execution (doing your loop) or if be a system process